# how to add custom fields into new & update post page?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field

I want to add new whole section of custom fields in admin UI of

- new post page
- edit post page

Could somebody suggest any nice code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this a simple and useful tutorial to do what you want:   http://wefunction.com/2009/10/revisited-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/

Comment: looks like `add_meta_box` is what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome! If this is the answer to your question please tick the check mark and select it as the chosen answer. Thanks!